# Searchable Android Dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary, searchview

I need to create an app which acts like a dictionary.

The a user can search the meaning of a word from a text file using the  `SearchView` widget from toolbar. In my code, I can only display the whole content inside the text file and I cannot perform the query.

Can anybody help me out? I have been struggling for a long time without a clue.

Below is my code (what I tried so far):

```
package issa.example.com.searchview;

        import android.app.SearchManager;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuInflater;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.widget.SeekBar;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView display;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        //handleIntent(getIntent());

      Intent searchIntent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(searchIntent.getAction())){

            String query = searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(SearchResultsActivity.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

try {
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("dictionary");


                int size = is.available();

                // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();

                // Convert the buffer into a string.
                String text = new String(buffer);

                // Finally stick the string into the text view.
                // Replace with whatever you need to have the text into.

                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                tv.setText(text);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Should never happen!
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }


 }
}
```

Comment: @Tom Lord. Thanks for edit. Do you have any idea about my question?

Comment: Sorry, I was only moderating the proposed edits list. I could try researching it, but have no experience in Android development.